# How to add recent search to searchbar in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
enter() {
            this.selection = this.matches[this.current];
            this.open = false;
        },
  change() {
            if (this.open == false) {
                this.open = true;
                this.current = 0;
            }
            
            
            if(this.search == "") {
                this.isSearchText = false;
            } else {
                this.isSearchText = true;
            }
            
        },
     inputChanged(event) {
            if (event.code == "ArrowUp" || event.code == "ArrowDown")
              return;
      
            this.filteredUsers = [];
      
            if (event.code == "Enter")
              return;
      
            var filtered = this.users.filter((user) => {
              return user.text.match(this.search)
            });
      
            this.isOpen = true
            this.filteredUsers.push(...filtered)
      
      
            // console.log(this.filteredUsers)
          },
   
     onArrow(event) {
            if (this.filteredUsers.length > 0) {
              this.arrowCounter = event.code == "ArrowDown" ? ++this.arrowCounter : --this.arrowCounter;
              if (this.arrowCounter >= this.filteredUsers.length)
                this.arrowCounter = (this.arrowCounter) % this.filteredUsers.length;
              else if (this.arrowCounter < 0)
                this.arrowCounter = this.filteredUsers.length + this.arrowCounter;
              this.setResult(this.filteredUsers[this.arrowCounter].text);
            }
          },
```

```html
<input class="form-control bg-light-blue" id="SearchText"  type="text" v-model="search"
        @keydown.enter = 'enter'
        @input = 'change'
        @keyup="inputChanged"
        @keydown.down="onArrow"
        @keydown.up="onArrow"
    />
```

Example:- In the Flipkart website in the searchbar if i type shoes, and then if i go back and again click and search bar previously visited searched items will be saved in the searchbar.

I am looking for the same functionality in vuejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the Flipkart site and inspected their search input.  It is an input tag combined with unordered list.  So I created this sample component.

**EDIT:** Added logic to show/hide search history.  Added history max length.

InputWithList.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="input-with-list">
    <h4>Input with List</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="searchValue" @keyup.enter="processSearch"
            @click="onClick" @input="onInput">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" @click="processSearch">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <ul class="list-group" v-if="showSearchHistory">
            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(item, index) in searchHistory" :key="index"
              @click="selectPreviousSearch(index)">{{ item }}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="clearHistory">Clear history</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        searchValue: '',
        searchHistory: [],
        showSearchHistory: false,
        searchHistoryMaxLength: 5
      }
    },
    methods: {
      processSearch() {
        if ( this.searchHistory.indexOf(this.searchValue) === -1) {
          this.searchHistory.push(this.searchValue);
          if (this.searchHistory.length > this.searchHistoryMaxLength) {
            // Remove the first (oldest) element
            this.searchHistory.shift();
          }
        }
        this.searchValue = '';
      },
      selectPreviousSearch(index) {
        this.searchValue = this.searchHistory[index];
        this.showSearchHistory = false;
      },
      clearHistory() {
        this.searchHistory = [];
        this.searchValue = '';
      },
      onClick() {
        // Toggle show/hide
        this.showSearchHistory = !this.showSearchHistory;
      },
      onInput() {
        this.showSearchHistory = false;
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  li:hover {
    background-color:gainsboro;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Its perfectly working fine, but how to set condition for Storing the text value As 5 only, I mean like when if user try to enter more than 5, Value should be update and previously stored text should be hide.

Comment: See the modification I made to method ```processSearch()```.  I also modified ```onClick()``` to toggle showing/hiding the search history.